# Force a USB drive with damaged boot sectors to stay connected

Tags: usb

I have accidentally damaged the boot sectors of a 16 GB MS-DOS formatted USB stick. When plugged in (OSX 10.9 or Unbuntu 13), it mounts for a split-second, then unmounts, endlessly.

There's around 7 GB of data on the key that I would like to copy. Any idea how I could force the disk to stay connected, in order to try grabbing the data or at least reformat it?

Comment: what does the device show in fdisk?

Comment: I'd like to be able to answer, but how do you list the devices with `fdisk`? `fdisk -l` does not work.

Comment: fdisk wouldn't work anyways if your unable to mount the device.  Are you sure the device itself is working.  USB drives have a limited lifespan.

Comment: The device is alive (the LED says so) but is not well: it just mounts on and off.

Comment: What do you mean by MS-DOS formatted USB stick? Define accidental damage of boot sector.

Comment: I mean FAT32 (formatted under OSX), but now it's just a damaged drive I guess. I damaged the drive by running a large download script from and to it, which probably resulted in writing over the boot partition.